# Who is this person in the Age of Ultron trailer that looks like Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, spider-man, avengers-age-of-ultron, marvel

I am already aware that Spider-Man is not in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. However, I was watching the trailer and I noticed something strange in the following scene:

[image: avengers trailer scene]

If you zoom the image in, it clearly appears to be Spider-Man along with the rest of the Avengers.

[image]

This made me wonder who this could be, if it can't be Spider-Man. Could it be Vision?

Comment: "Is that Spiderman in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*?" ... "I am already aware that Spiderman is not in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*." ... So, what is the question?

Comment: Who is that guy?

Comment: An extremely well editted image ( cant call it photoshopped as there are other softwares too )

Comment: @stud I would say the term "Photoshopped" has become sufficiently well-known that you can use it to describe any sort of image manipulation or trickery.

Comment: Downvoted because this is an obvious Photoshop, which is easy to disprove by looking at the trailer.

Comment: Got tricked by Photoshopped image

Comment: @alexwlchan Just showing my support for GIMP :)

Comment: Not a good question, but also not unclear.

Comment: This does not need to be re-opened for the sake of close-reason semantics.

Comment: @ArunkumarTK I just don't get why you would say "I was watching the trailer and I noticed something.." when you were clearly **not** watching the trailer but just a Vine or a picture or whatever :/

Comment: If you were watching the trailer, you wouldn't have seen Spider-man in it.

Comment: OP was on 9gag.

Answer (score 10):

No. That image has been photoshopped.

The images you posted appear to have been taken from [this vine](https://vine.co/v/O0QlWWnXQIr) which is specifically described as

> #spiderman added to the #AgeofUltron trailer

Here is the same shot from the unedited trailer.

[image: Unphotoshopped screencap]

Screencap taken from the trailer on Marvel's official Youtube channel.

The added character is certainly Spider-Man, and not The Vision, who appears at the end of the trailer.

Comment: -1 from GIMP but +1 from Photoshop :-)

Comment: Last I tried using it, GIMP couldn't handle motion graphics or videos. It's been a long time, though.

Comment: Most tricks are played on screenshots rather than a video clip since its easier to edit .

Comment: @stud we actually found the source of the image, and it's a vine, so they appear to have edited several frames in a row.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Ohh , people do take a lot of pains to create some publicity and fun . And by "we" do you mean you had a team tracking the source ?

Comment: by "we" i mean the chat room. The source, by the way: https://vine.co/v/O0QlWWnXQIr

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Cool. Is this chat room a public one as it looks like an interesting one ?

Comment: yes. hit the site list drop-down at the top of the screen and click the 'chat' link; Mos Eisley is the most active room, usually, but there's a couple others.

Comment: @stud anyone with more than 20 rep can join us in the chat room. There's a link up top in the menu, sometimes there's one in the sidebar, or [you can just click here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) to go directly to our main room.

Comment: phantom42 , @MichaelEdenfield Thank you .

Comment: @phantom42 GIMP can handle motion graphics, it's possible to create gifs in GIMP just like in Photoshop.  Not sure about video though.

Comment: This is from IGN's fan made trailer.